# KendoMultiSelect close its dropdown on mouseout automatically

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I am using KendoMultiselect control in my ASP.NET web-forms project. I wish to close its dynamic dropdown, when the mouse leaves the dropdown option area. I have tried many options such as below with the comment.

Here is the code snippet.

```
<select id="selInvestors" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder=""></select>

<script language='javascript'>
var myJsonObj = [{text: "Client", val: "4" },{text: "Employees", val: "16" },{text: "Other", val: "32" }];

       $(function () {
                $("#selInvestors").kendoMultiSelect({
                    dataTextField: "text",
                    dataValueField: "val",
                    dataSource: myJsonObj
                });

                var selinvCtl = $("#selInvestors").data("kendoMultiSelect");
                $('#selInvestors').parent().css({ "width": "355" });

                 //The below statement is even executing when i hover over the dropdown options. I dont know why ?  I want to close the downdown, whenever the mouse cursor goes out of the dropdown control.

                $("ul[id*='selInvestors']").mouseout(function () { console.log('I am out'); /*selinvCtl.close();*/ });
     });

    </script>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try .mouseleave() instead of .mouseout()

[see example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseleave_mouseout)